# Show each records of groupby sql query

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have an ads table like this:

```
 id  adid  approveby
 1   10    MR A    
 2   11    MR A 
 3   12    MR B
```

I would like to count total record of MR A  and echo each record out so I have this sql query:

```
$sql = "SELECT *, count(*) AS `totaladsapproved` FROM ads GROUP BY approveby";
$result = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result->execute();
foreach ($result as $row){
 echo "Name: $row[approveby]"." - Total ads approved: $row[totaladsapproved] <br>";
  for($i=0;$i<$row['totaladsapproved'];$i++){
  echo "Ad ID: $row[adid] <br>"
  }
}
```

But it only shows adid 10 twice. Here is the result i got:

```
Name: MR A - Total ads approved: 2
      AD ID: 10
      AD ID: 10
```

I would like to show AD ID 10 and then AD ID 11...What should I do to achieve this?

Many thanks

Comment: Maybe if you used `$i` in the `for` loop instead of `echo "Ad ID: $row[adid]`, you would get the effect of iteration.

Answer (score 0):

your query is grouping so you would not see each id

use following, this will give you count of total "aproveby" present for each row

```
SELECT id,
       adid,
      approveby,
      (select count(*) from ads where approveby
        = t1.approveby) AS `totaladsapproved`
 FROM ads t1
```

if you want to restrict to MR A you can use `where clause`

Answer (score 0):

The code has a lot of problems. They are addressed below one by one.

#### Undefined `$i`

Your code reads:

```
foreach ($result as $row){
    echo "Name: $row[approveby]"." - Total ads approved: $row[totaladsapproved] <br>";
    for ($i; $i < $row['totaladsapproved']; $i ++) {
        echo "Ad ID: $row[adid] <br>";
    }
}
```

First thing to notice is that `$i` is not initialized but you use it to iterate in a `for()` loop. PHP is nice and, besides showing you a notice you don't care of, because of the numeric context it uses `0` instead of `NULL` on the first loop when it handles `$i` to check the condition and to increment `$i`.

The correct way to do it is:

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < $row['totaladsapproved']; $i ++) {
```

not only because of what I mentioned above but also because using your code, on the next `foreach()` iteration, `$i` starts with `2` and the `for()` loop skips the first two iterations.

#### The logic error in the loops

You get one row in variable `$row` but then you just print it `2` times (or as many times `$row['totaladsapproved']` says) without getting the subsequent rows from the result set.

To fix it you could get new rows from the result set inside the `for()` loop. I don't provide code here because it doesn't matter, the query is wrong anyway.

#### General considerations about the queries that use `GROUP BY`

If you want to get the records then do not use `GROUP BY`. `GROUP BY approveby` produces a single row from all the rows that have the same value for `approveby`.

In the `SELECT` clause of a query that has a `GROUP BY` clause you can use only:

- the columns that also [appear in the `GROUP BY` clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html);
- other columns that are functionally dependent on the fields that appear in the `GROUP BY` clause; this means you can use any column of the table **only if** the table's `PK` or an `UNIQUE INDEX` of it appears in the `GROUP BY` clause;
- any column of the table if it is used as an argument of a[`GROUP BY` aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html).

Any column that appear in the `SELECT` clause and is not described in the list above renders the query invalid (according to the `SQL` standard).

`MySQL` extends the standard and allows such invalid queries (as long as they are syntactically correct, of course) but it does not guarantee anything about the values of these columns returned in the result set.

> ... a `MySQL` extension to the use of `GROUP BY` is to permit the `SELECT` list, `HAVING` condition, or `ORDER BY` list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns are not functionally dependent on `GROUP BY` columns. This causes `MySQL` to accept the (...) query. In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate, which is probably not what you want.

#### The query is incorrect

Back to your query, because the columns `id` and `adid` are not included in the list above, using `*` in the `SELECT` list renders the query invalid and the values returned for columns `id` and `adid` indeterminate.

In your case it happened that for `approvedby == 'MR A'`, `MySQL` decided to return (`1`, `10`) for (`id`, `adid`). It could return (`2`, `11`) instead tomorrow, after you add or remove some rows from the table (or when the table is dumped and imported on a different server). It could even return (`1`, `11`) and it is still right. It could even return `-1` or `NULL` or whatever value it wants and you still cannot blame it because `indeterminate` is something that is not settled or decided.

#### The correct query

The correct query for your case is as simple as:

```
SELECT * FROM ads ORDER BY approveby
```

Using `ORDER BY` is important to get the rows having the same value for `approveby` one next to the other. Then, in the PHP code you run through the returned result set, count the rows for each value of `approveby`, store it in another list or do whatever you want with it.

```
$howMany = array();        // store the number of rows in each group
$current = '--fake--';     // the current group (use a value that does not appear in the data)
$count   = 0;              // the number of rows in the current group
foreach ($result as $row) {
    // Check if a new group started
    if ($row['approvedby'] != $current) {
        // Store the value for the current 'approveby'
        $howMany[$current] = $count;

        // Start counting for the new value of 'approvedby'
        $current = $row['approveby'];
        $count = 0;
    }

    // Count the new occurrence
    $count ++;
}
// Store the number of rows from the last group
$howMany[$current] = $count;
// Remove the fake value inserted on the first loop
unset($howMany['--fake--']);           // Use the initial value of $current
```

If you don't need the number of rows in each group before enumerating the rows in the group then your code becomes even simpler: remove from the code above all the references to variable `$howMany`.